# unable to connect ms sql server from azure app

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have Azure app and SQL Database.SQL URL like `jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=xxxxx` that one try connect my local tomcat,its successfully connected.but when try connected from Azure app,I am getting exception

```
 [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: java:jboss/DB/DS: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1320)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.fillTo(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1136)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open server "App-server" requested by the login.  The login failed.
```

Comment: To clarify: You're using SQL Database, not SQL Server (based on your connection string). Did you add your Azure service to the SQL Database firewall, to allow for connections?

Comment: Sorry.I have used SQL Database and newbie for azure.can you explain about Azure service to the SQL Database firewall, to allow for connections, any screenshot if possible.Thanks

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: I can access SQL Database from my local machine.but i can't use from azure app server (VM) from sql Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i can't use from azure app server (VM) from sql Database

Do you mean you application hosting on Azure VM?

If I understand it correctly, you should add Azure VM's public IP address to sql server firewall.

Via Azure portal to add VM's IP address:

[image]

Also you should add port **1433** to VM's **NSG inbound rules** and **OS firewall settings**.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you have set On the "Allow access to Azure services" setting on Azure portal for the Azure SQL database or its logical server. Please see below image.

You need to also specify the user@database on the connection string. Please read [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AccessACloudDatabaseAzureAsASourceUsingDataVirtualization?_sscc=t) for more details on how to build the connection string.

[image]

Comment: I can access SQL Database from my local machine.but i can't use from azure app server (VM) from sql Database

Comment: I added instructions on how to build the connection string.